# How to extract images from segmentations

Tags: machine-learning, opencv3.0, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I have segmented an image using scikit image and I want to know how to extract the segmented region as a separate image.

```
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.morphology import watershed, disk
from skimage import data
from skimage.filters import rank
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
from skimage import io, color, filters as filters
from skimage.measure import regionprops, label

import cv2
import numpy as np

image = color.rgb2gray(io.imread('<path>/Roll/fd.jpg'))
denoised = rank.median(image, disk(2))

markers = rank.gradient(denoised, disk(5)) < 25
markers = ndi.label(markers)[0]

gradient = rank.gradient(denoised, disk(2))

labels = watershed(gradient, markers)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(15, 15), sharex=True, sharey=True, subplot_kw={'adjustable':'box-forced'})
ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
ax[0].set_title("Original")

ax[1].imshow(gradient, cmap=plt.cm.spectral, interpolation='nearest')
ax[1].set_title("Local Gradient")

ax[2].imshow(markers, cmap=plt.cm.spectral, interpolation='nearest')
ax[2].set_title("Markers")

ax[3].imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
ax[3].imshow(labels, cmap=plt.cm.spectral, interpolation='nearest', alpha=.7)
ax[3].set_title("Segmented")

for a in ax:
    a.axis('off')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

and i got the following output, what I want to do is extract the images displayed below separately which are also mentioned by the segmentation

[image]

Comment: I'd use regionprops on the labeled image, and for each region grab its bounding box, which you can then slice out and save.  See http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops